# Eclipse and Zend Debugger breaks in the first line always, despite having unchecked that option

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-debugger

I unchecked the *break on first line* option in the PHP debug configuration, but it still breaks in the first line, no matter what.
How can I prevent this?

I'm using MacOSX, Eclipse PDT 3.0.2 with the Zend Debugger.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a lot of googling I found out how to solve this problem. There are three places where the "Break on first line" configuration can be set.

- Window -> Prefrences -> PHP -> Debug
- Project -> Properties -> PHP Debug
- Run -> Debug Configurations -> PHP Web Page -> `<Your configuration>` -> Server-Tab

Where the latter one overrides the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this forgotten question and saving it from oblivion! :D

Comment: In my configuration (MacOSX Mavericks, Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2, PHP Dev Tools 3.0.0, Xdebug) the 'Break at First Line' checkbox was in Debug As... -> Debug Configurations... -> PHP Web Application -> index (2), with index (2) being the name of my debug configuration.

Comment: I'm using eclipse for PHP 2023-06-R-win32-x86_64  and I had to restart the IDE after unchecking it in all 3 places in order for it to begin respecting my decisions.