# Eclipse Luna with xdebug always breaks at first line

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I am using Eclipse Luna.  My problem is that when debugging a PHP site, Eclipse always breaks on the first line in index.html despite the fact that in the Debug Configuration I have unchecked the option "Break at First Line."

There are two similar questions on Stack Overflow here: [Question 1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11324156%2Fprevent-xdebug-to-break-at-first-line-of-index-file&ei=IHoHVMmDDMLJgwSkl4HICw&usg=AFQjCNHzqZUrBGMTMaMeCVSOHA6LD_w3WQ&bvm=bv.74115972,d.eXY) and here: [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071397/eclipse-and-zend-debugger-breaks-in-the-first-line-always-despite-having-unchec).  It seems the problem can be solved by unchecking 'Break at First Line' in both the debug configuration options and in the project properties options.

However, in Eclipse Luna, I am prevented from configuring xdebug in project properties.  There is no option to configure xdebug there in this release of Eclipse.  It can only be configured by setting up a debug configuration.  So the solutions in the two S.O. questions don't apply to me.

Answer (score 2):

as explained in the first answer to [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071397/eclipse-and-zend-debugger-breaks-in-the-first-line-always-despite-having-unchec), you must to disable the "Break at first line" in the Debug configuration:

Run -> Debug Configurations -> PHP Web Page ->  -> Server-Tab

Once done, go to the Debug perspective and restart the PHP Web Application process.
I have just resolved your problem with Eclipse Luna and XDebug.

Comment: Seems you also have to restart Eclipse after un-checking 'Break at first line'. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324156/prevent-xdebug-to-break-at-first-line-of-index-file